# use pivot longer to lengthen multiple columns R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have the raw data in the following format: [raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR7BJ.png)

I am trying to get the data in the following format: [wanted data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWDbz.png)

I am using the following code long_data <- pivot_longer(df,c("Q1 Value","Q2 Value","Q1 Ref Text","Q2 Ref Text")), but it is putting the Value and Ref Text columns in the same column, when i would like them to speperate